# how to create query which can calculate time difference?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have and index with following documents:

```
{name: 'Device1', type: 'start', 'eventTime': '2013-02-19 12:00:00'}
{name: 'Device2', type: 'start', 'eventTime': '2013-02-19 12:02:00'}
{name: 'Device1', type: 'stop', 'eventTime': '2013-02-19 12:45:00'}
{name: 'Device2', type: 'stop', 'eventTime': '2013-02-19 12:50:00'}
```

I would like to create a query which will return for me a new field with time differences between eventTime's, faceted by device name and regards with field type. For the example it should be:

```
{name: 'Device1', 'type': 'it really doesnt matter', eventTime: 'also doesnt matter', duration: '00:45:00'}
{name 'Device2', 'type': 'it really doesnt matter', eventTime: 'also doesnt matter', duration: '00:48:00'}
```

Is it possible with elastic search query language?

Answer (score 7):

I don't believe this is possible with the way you have each document currently. If you store the documents as:

```
{name: 'Device1', startTime: '2013-02-19 12:00:00', endTime: '2013-02-19 12:45:00'}
{name: 'Device2', startTime: '2013-02-19 12:02:00', endTime: '2013-02-19 12:50:00'}
```

You could then return a [script field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html) which is the time difference.

```
{    
  "query" : {
    ...
  },
  "script_fields" : {
    "timedifference" : {
      "script" : "doc['endTime'].value - doc['startTime'].value"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, but unfortunately I can't index it in this way

Comment: Can these script_fields be implemented in kibana interface?

Comment: Not by default as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at the [elapsed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elapsed.html) logstash filter.

For your use case, you'll have to tag the start document with a *start_tag* and stop document with *end_tag*. You can use 'name' as unique id field.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Searching for the same thing, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37359000/2161698) I found a good example to answer this question, using elapsed filters as Ana said, and combining it with the aggregate filter.

The idea is to measure the time of each stage and then aggregate the timing information between events into a new event.

So following the example provided in the link, if you have this logs:

> ```
> 2016-05-19T02:55:29.003 00e02f2f-32d5-9509-870a-f80e54dc8775 system1Enter
> 2016-05-19T02:55:29.200 00e02f2f-32d5-9509-870a-f80e54dc8775 system1Exit
> 2016-05-19T02:55:29.205 00e02f2f-32d5-9509-870a-f80e54dc8775 system2Enter
> 2016-05-19T02:55:29.453 00e02f2f-32d5-9509-870a-f80e54dc8775 system2Exit
> ```

We define three elapsed filters (one for each stage in1, 1->2 and in2) and then three aggregate filters in order to sum all the timing information.

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => ["message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{UUID:messageId} %{WORD:event}"]
    add_tag => [ "%{event}" ]
  }
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp", "ISO8601"]
  }
  # Measures the execution time of system1
  elapsed {
    unique_id_field => "messageId"
    start_tag => "system1Enter"
    end_tag => "system1Exit"
    new_event_on_match => true
    add_tag => ["in1"]
  }
  # Measures the execution time of system2
  elapsed {
    unique_id_field => "messageId"
    start_tag => "system2Enter"
    end_tag => "system2Exit"
    new_event_on_match => true
    add_tag => ["in2"]
  }
  # Measures the time between system1 and system2
  elapsed {
    unique_id_field => "messageId"
    start_tag => "system1Exit"
    end_tag => "system2Enter"
    new_event_on_match => true
    add_tag => ["1->2"]
  }
  # Records the execution time of system1
  if "in1" in [tags] and "elapsed" in [tags] {
    aggregate {
      task_id => "%{messageId}"
      code => "map['report'] = [(event['elapsed_time']*1000).to_i]"
      map_action => "create"
    }
  }
  # Records the time between system1 and system2
  if "1->2" in [tags] and "elapsed" in [tags] {
    aggregate {
      task_id => "%{messageId}"
      code => "map['report'] << (event['elapsed_time']*1000).to_i"
      map_action => "update"
    }
  }
  # Records the execution time of system2
  if "in2" in [tags] and "elapsed" in [tags] {
    aggregate {
      task_id => "%{messageId}"
      code => "map['report'] << (event['elapsed_time']*1000).to_i; event['report'] = map['report'].join(':')"
      map_action => "update"
      end_of_task => true
    }
  }
}
```

After the first two events, you'll get a new event which shows that 197ms have been spent in system1:

```
{
                 "@timestamp" => "2016-05-21T04:20:51.731Z",
                       "tags" => [ "elapsed", "elapsed_match", "in1" ],
               "elapsed_time" => 0.197,
                  "messageId" => "00e02f2f-32d5-9509-870a-f80e54dc8775",
    "elapsed_timestamp_start" => "2016-05-19T00:55:29.003Z"
}
```

Again, all credits go to the autor of the original answer :)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13661139)

Comment: Edited to include essential parts of the original answer here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scripted_metric to get the duration.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "d_ids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
          "aggs": {
            "duration": {
              "scripted_metric": { 
                "map_script": "if (doc.type.value == \"stop\") { params._agg.end = doc.eventTime.value; } else { params._agg.start = doc.eventTime.value; }",
                "reduce_script": "long start = 0; long end = 0; for(h in params._aggs) { if(h.start != null) { start = h.start; } if (h.end != null) { end = h.end; } } return (end - start);"
              }
            }
          }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the response from the above query:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 4,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "d_ids": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Device1",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "duration": {
            "value": 2700000
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "Device2",
          "doc_count": 2,
          "duration": {
            "value": 2880000
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The durations are in milliseconds