# Change date on event created by Elapsed or Aggregate filters

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

When using `new_event_on_match` with elapsed filter a new event is created, with a fresh timestamp. The Aggregate filter adds a new event with a fresh timestamp as well.

I would like to use the timestamp from the original events, which is now available in the field `elapsed_timestamp_start`. How can I replace `@timestamp` in the newly created event?

Can I use a `Date` filter inside an `Elapsed` filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, just note that only the `elapsed` filter creates a new event, the `aggregate` filter doesn't and will push whatever information has been aggregated so far into the last event.

In order to provide some context, the previous question you're referring to is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37353365/calculating-time-between-events).

You can achieve what you want, simply by adding a `date` filter just after the last `elapsed` filter, so as to modify the event newly created by the upstream `elapsed` filter. Also note that we first need to convert the `elapsed_timestamp_start` field to a string before trying to match the date because it's a Logstash timestamp object (created by the `elapsed` filter)

```
  if "elapsed" in [tags] {
    mutate {
      convert => {"elapsed_timestamp_start" => "string"}
    }
    date {
      match => ["elapsed_timestamp_start", "ISO8601"]
    }
  }
```