# Can I calculate time difference between consecutive document in elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, spring-data-elasticsearch, elastic-cloud

Suppose there are 3 records,the timestamp of first record is 10:45:00 and timestamp of second record is 10:47:00 and timestamp of next record is 10:50:00;the time difference between first and second record is of 2 minutes and time difference between second and third record is of 3 minutes.
It is possible to calculate time difference between consecutive documents?

Comment: Are you using Logstash to ingest your documents? If yes, the following answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37353365/calculating-time-between-events/37359000#37359000

Comment: thanks for your heads up.documents are already stored in index, using elastic query I wanna calculate difference?

Comment: How many documents are we talking ?

Comment: There is a stream which stores the records in elastic index..through elastic query I wanna calculate the difference between timestamps

Comment: how does that stream of events go to elasticsearch?

Comment: using flink and kafka I am storing events in ealsticsearch.

Comment: @vinayakfutak did you get solution?