# Elastic search - exclude records by time difference

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's have a source:

```
_doc:1, date: 2018-01-01 00:00:00, longitude: 12.00, latitude: 1.00, other: 1
_doc:2, date: 2018-01-01 00:01:00, longitude: 12.00, latitude: 1.00, other: 0
_doc:3, date: 2018-01-01 00:02:00, longitude: 12.00, latitude: 1.00, other: 0
_doc:4, date: 2018-01-01 00:03:00, longitude: 12.00, latitude: 1.00, other: 1
_doc:5, date: 2018-01-01 00:07:00, longitude: 12.00, latitude: 1.00, other: 13
_doc:6, date: 2018-01-01 00:10:00, longitude: 12.00, latitude: 1.00, other: 1
```

Is it possible to find results based on time difference with previous document?
The rule is quite simple, if time difference is greater or equals to X or other property is higher than 0 then record has to be scored, including aggregation - sum distance by lat, lon.

I went through Elastic Search docs and actually did not find what could solve the issue at all, distance aggregations could  work, as well as exclude/include by other property. The main issue is time difference. How to solve it ?

During search - I found serial differencing aggregation, however this doesn't solve it at all.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-serialdiff-aggregation.html

Comment: "difference with previous document" doesn't mean anything in ES since there's no concept of insertion order. You need to pre-process your log lines at indexing time using Logstash for instance, as demonstrated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37353365/calculating-time-between-events/37359000#37359000

Comment: hmm, the problem is at index time - there is possiblity that previous record is not correct one - so it changes all the time

Comment: With the solution I linked to you can definitely support that since the `aggregate` filter can hold events into memory until the correct "next" event comes in.

Comment: I don't have logstash included in tech-stack, however if I will not find other way, then I will use. What do you think about https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html in this context ?

Comment: That will not solve your issue because you need to relate two documents together in order to compute a diff. Depending on the number of documents you have, you'll need to avoid scripts. The best way is to do any heavy computations at indexing time.

Comment: I understand, thank you for help :)