# Painless script to get time difference between two logs entries separated by a unique ID

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless, kibana-7

I am trying to get time difference between two log entries like RequestExecuted and RequestReceived with a filed name MessageIdentifier. These valuse are linked by unique id named TransactionId. Below is my code to do the logic.

```
int timetaken=0;      
int start=0;      
String TransactionId;      
int end=0;   

for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){        
    if (doc['dissect.MessageIdentifier'].value[i]=='RequestReceived') {          
        start=params._source.dissect.timestamp[i];          
        TransactionId=params._source.dissect.TransactionId[i];
     }        
    if( doc['dissect.MessageIdentifier'].value[i] =='RequestExecuted' 
        && params._source.dissect.TransactionId == TransactionId) {          
            end=params._source.dissect.timestamp[i];          
            timetaken = end - start; 
            return timetaken;
    }
}
```

When i compile my painless script it gives me an error:

```
lang": "painless",
    "caused_by": {
     "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
     "reason": "Attempting to address a non-array-like type [java.lang.String] as an array."
```

Here is the index snippet:

[image]

Your help will be highly obliged.

Comment: What are you iterating over with `for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)`? You only have access to the current doc's context, not all of them.  Also, are you using `script_field`s or `scripted_metric` aggs?

Comment: This is something you need to do at ingest time (with Logstash for instance). See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37353365/calculating-time-between-events/37359000#37359000

Comment: @jzzfs I am actually iterating over doc size so. its just an example. I am using scripted matric aggression. Logstash is actually not an option here. Thats why trying to create scripted filed when the data is already in elasticsearch.

Comment: so your `dissect` field is an array of items?

Comment: @jzzfs yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming your `dissect` field is an array of nested objects you can do the following:

Create index

```
PUT dissect
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
       "dissect" : {
         "type": "nested", 
          "properties" : {
            "MessageIdentifier" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fielddata": true,
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "TransationId" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fielddata": true,
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "timestamp" : {
              "type" : "date"
            }
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Sync a sample

```
POST dissect/_doc
{
  "dissect": [
    {
      "MessageIdentifier": "abc",
      "timestamp": 200,
      "TransationId": "xyz"
    },
    {
      "MessageIdentifier": "RequestReceived",
      "timestamp": 300,
      "TransationId": "xyz"
    },
    {
      "MessageIdentifier": "RequestExecuted",
      "timestamp": 400,
      "TransationId": "xyz"
    }
  ]
}
```

Run your script field

```
GET dissect/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
    "timetaken": {
      "script": {
        "source": """
        int timetaken = 0;      
        int start = 0;      
        String TransactionId;      
        int end = 0;   

        for (def dissect_item : params._source['dissect']) {
          if (dissect_item['MessageIdentifier'] == 'RequestReceived') {          
                start = dissect_item['timestamp'];          
                TransactionId = dissect_item['TransactionId'];
            }

            if( dissect_item['MessageIdentifier'] =='RequestExecuted' 
                && dissect_item['TransactionId'] == TransactionId) {          
                    end = dissect_item['timestamp'];          
                    timetaken = end - start; 
                    return timetaken;
            }
        }
        """
      }
    }
  }
}
```

yielding

```
[
  {
    "_index":"dissect",
    "_type":"_doc",
    "_id":"_v7u43EBW-D5QnrWmjtM",
    "_score":1.0,
    "fields":{
      "timetaken":[
        100              <-----
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

---

Key takeaway: you don't wanna be iterating over a hard-coded length of 10 but instead as `for (def dissect_item : params._source['dissect'])`

Comment: man thank you so much. This is exactly i wanted. And your answer explained the whole concept. I was new to painless but now have some better understanding. Many thanks.