# Logstash: is it possible to somehow add a field with a date difference of two or more log lines?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-configuration, filebeat

The question is as follows, I upload logs to elasticsearch using filebeat and logstash.

```
"03.08.2020 10:56:38","Event LClick","Type Menu","t=0","beg"

"03.08.2020 10:56:38","Event LClick","Type Menu","Detail Impale","t=109","end"

"03.08.2020 10:56:40","Event LClick","t=1981","beg"

"03.08.2020 10:56:40","Event LClick","t=2090","end"

"03.08.2020 10:56:41","Event LClick","Type ToolBar","t=3026","beg"

"03.08.2020 10:56:44","Event FormActivate","Name SomeName","t=5444"

"03.08.2020 10:56:43","Event LClick","Type ToolBar","Detail Test","t=4477","end"
```

These are logs of actions performed by users in web forms. Each action has a beginning ("beg" at the end of a line) and an end ("end" at the end of a line).

I need to calculate the difference in time for which the user performed the action and output it as a field, if possible (even if it is zero).

Example: "03.08.2020 10:56:44" - "03.08.2020 10:56:41" = 3 seconds (This should be a new field)

Maybe I need to combine the fields somehow?

If there is a solution for subtracting dates inside the logstash, then how can I implement this for actions that have other actions between the beginning and the end, for example "Event FormActivate".

Maybe this is solved by certain queries already inside elasticsearch.

I am a complete newbie and would appreciate any help.
My logstash config now:

```
input {
    beats {
        port => '5044'
    }
}
 filter {
    mutate {
        remove_field => [ '@version', 'input', 'host', 'ecs', 'agent' ]
        remove_tag => [ 'beats_input_codec_plain_applied' ]
    }
    grok {
        patterns_dir => ['./patterns']
        match => { 'message' => '%{TIME:timestamp}(","Event\s)(?<event>([^"]+))(","Form\s)?(?<form>([^"]+))?(","ParentType\s)?(?<parent_type>([^"]+))?(","ParentName\s)?(?<parent_name>([^"]+))?(","Type\s)?(?<type>([^"]+))?(","Name\s)?(?<name>([^"]+))?(","Detail\s)?(?<detail>([^"]+))?(","t=)?(?<t>([\d]+))?' }
    }
    date {
        match => [ 'timestamp', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss' ]
        timezone => 'Europe/Moscow'
        target => '@timestamp'
        remove_field => 'timestamp'
    }
    mutate {
        rename => ['log', 'user_path']
        rename => ['@timestamp', 'logdate']
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ['localhost:9200']
        index => 'test'
    }
}
```

***Update:***

I tried to comprehend the actions in the thread suggested by Val. But I still didn't succeed. This is what I did with the logstash config:

```
 filter {
    grok {
        patterns_dir => ['./patterns']
        match => { 'message' => '%{TIME:timestamp}(","Event\s)(?<event>([^"]+))(","Form\s)?(?<form>([^"]+))?(","ParentType\s)?(?<parent_type>([^"]+))?(","ParentName\s)?(?<parent_name>([^"]+))?(","Type\s)?(?<type>([^"]+))?(","Name\s)?(?<name>([^"]+))?(","Detail\s)?(?<detail>([^"]+))?(","t=)?(?<t>([\d]+))?(",")?(?<status>(end|beg))?' }
        add_tag => [ '%{status}' ]
    }
    date {
        match => [ 'timestamp', 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss' ]
    }
    elapsed {
        unique_id_field => 'event'
        start_tag => 'beg'
        end_tag => 'end'
        new_event_on_match => true
        add_tag => ['1->2']
    }
    if '1->2' in [tags] and 'elapsed' in [tags] {
        aggregate {
            task_id => '%{event}'
            code => 'map["report"] = [(event["elapsed_time"]*1000).to_i]'
            map_action => 'create'
            end_of_task => true
        }
    }
}
```

But it just doesn't work. It seems to me that I am very confused:(

Maybe if I show what I want to see in elasticsearch it will be better. For seven lines of logs (logs at the beginning of the post) it should look like this:

```
{
                 "username" => "I will get the username from the log path and I want it to get here too",
               "elapsed_time" => date difference,
                  "event" => "event from line",
    "elapsed_timestamp_start" => "start time"
}
```

From seven lines of logs in elasticsearch, there should be three such records.
Please help me write a filter for this task. Thank you!

Another question to the documentation for the Aggregate filter plugin:

```
 You should be very careful to set Logstash filter workers to 1 (-w 1 flag) for this filter to work correctly otherwise events may be processed out of sequence and unexpected results will occur.
```

I could not find an answer where I need to add this flag. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Or maybe I can somehow combine the "beg" line and the "end" line and just output them into one record in elasticsearch: start of action, end of action, action itself, etc.?

Comment: This thread should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37353365/calculating-time-between-events/37359000#37359000

Comment: @Val I tried to figure it out, but only got more confused. If it's not difficult for you, look at the update of my post. In fact, it is specially for you. Thank you.